# I need output ( create colmun) how many cities for every country by using the same query ( with )

Tags: sql, with-statement

```
WITH city_count_per_country AS
  (SELECT
    country_name,
    count(city_id) AS count
  
  FROM dim_city
   
  GROUP BY 1),

average_count AS
   (SELECT
    avg(count) AS avg
  FROM city_count_per_country)

SELECT country_name
FROM city_count_per_country, average_count
WHERE count > average_count.avg
```

Result:

```
+-------------------+
| country_name  |   |
+-------------------+ |
+-------------------+
| Germany        |  |
+-------------------+
| France         |  |
+-------------------+
| Colombia       |  |
+-------------------+
| Russia         |  |
+-------------------+
| Australia      |  |
+-------------------+
| United States  |  |
+-------------------+
| Argentina      |  |
+-------------------+
| Brazil         |  |
+-------------------+
| Mexico         |  |
+-------------------+
| Spain          |  |
+-------------------+
| Canada         |  |
+-------------------+
| United Kingdom |  |
+-------------------+
| India          |  |
+-------------------+
```

Comment: Please user modern join syntax, not that syntax from the 80s.

Comment: not sure I understand what you're trying to get ? what are you missing in your output ?

Comment: Please mention which dbms of what version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the number of city of a country you can just use `count` column from `city_count_per_country` in your final output. It's always better to use proper join syntax. So I have used inner join. `Count` is a reserved word so it's better not to use it as column name so I have use `country_count` instead. Please check below query:

```
WITH city_count_per_country AS
  (SELECT
    country_name,
    count(city_id) AS country_count
  
  FROM dim_city
   
  GROUP BY country_name),

average_count AS
   (SELECT
    avg(country_count) AS avg
  FROM city_count_per_country)

SELECT country_name, country_count
FROM city_count_per_country inner join average_count
on country_count> average_count.avg
```

You can also use window function (if your dbms permits) to calculate average within the same CTE. Please check Query#2.

```
 create table dim_city (country_name varchar(10),city_id int);
 insert into dim_city values('russia',3);
 insert into dim_city values('russia',2);
 insert into dim_city values('russia',1);
 insert into dim_city values('Germany',12);
 insert into dim_city values('Germany',10);
 insert into dim_city values('bd',20);
 insert into dim_city values('bd',21);
 insert into dim_city values('bd',22);
```

Query #1:

```
 WITH city_count_per_country AS
       (SELECT
         country_name,
         count(city_id) AS country_count
       
       FROM dim_city
        
       GROUP BY country_name),
     
     average_count AS
        (SELECT
         avg(country_count) AS avg
       FROM city_count_per_country)
     
     SELECT country_name, country_count
     FROM city_count_per_country inner join average_count
     on country_count average_count.avg
```

Output:

| country_name | country_count |
| --- | --- |
| bd | 3 |
| russia | 3 |

Query #2:

```
 with city_count_per_country as
 (  
   SELECT
     country_name,
     count(city_id) AS country_count,avg(count(city_id))over() as average_country_count
   
   FROM dim_city
    
   GROUP BY country_name
 )
 select country_name,country_count from city_count_per_country
 where country_count  average_country_count
 GO
```

Output:

| country_name | country_count |
| --- | --- |
| bd | 3 |
| russia | 3 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a66df0b4282e2efa6bc87c47a1efe5bf)*